# don't see keyboard in tablet mode on surface book

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface, virtual-keyboard, tablet-mode

I just bought Surface Book and have the strange problem. When I detach keyboard and use it in tablet mode and try to print something in text field, virtual keyboard appears only in some applications. For example it works in Edge/Bing and Skype, but doesn't work in Chrome/Google and many other applications.

Of course I can use accessibility keyboard option, but it's just workaround.

Is it some known issue or it can be fixed (maybe some hidden settings)?

**UPDATE:** Virtual keyboard works only for Microsoft's products, in all other applications it doesn't show up.

**Update2**: It works for any tablet Apps, but for desktop applications it depends, for example:

1. Edge - yes
2. Chrome - no
3. Google Hangout - no
4. Notepad++ - no
5. Visual Studio - sometimes yes, sometimes not
6. Excel - yes
7. Word - no
8. Skype - yes

**Update3**: After many updates it looks like it's working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Right click/bring up the context menu of the taskbar
2. Select `Show touch keyboard button`

[image]

3. Then you should see a keyboard icon and if you press it there pop-up a keyboard
   [image]

Comment: yes, it works, but I think it's just workaround regarding this Windows bug.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Settings! (Windwos + I)
2. Go to Devices -> Typing
3. Scroll down and toggle on: Automatically show the touch keyboard in windowed apps when there's no keyboard attached to your device:
   [image]

Comment: on this place I see other option: "Show the touch keyboard or handwriting panel when not in tablet mode and there's no keyboard attached" and it's already on.

Comment: it works in all Microsoft's products, but doesn't work in Chrome, which I used most.